# I'm attempting to convert a reaction giving discord bot to a bot that sends a message when a specific react is used. I am unable to get it to respond

Tags: javascript, botframework, discord, discord.js

I was able to create a bot that is able to give a role when a specific reaction is used, but instead want the bot to send a message in chat when a specific reaction is used. the original code (for reaction bot) is commented out, and the error I have is at the bottom

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE','REACTION']
});
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const Yard = '709954577713201173'
const MessageNumber = '7710157795517005854'

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

bot.login(token);

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    console.log('Message Reaction Add Top');

    reaction.channel.send = async () => {
        try {
        //applyRole instead of reaction.channel.send
            let emojiName = reaction.emoji.name;
            let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find;
            let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id == user.id);
            if (reaction.emoji.name === '⚔️' && member) {
                // if (role && member) {
                console.log('React and Member Found');
                await reaction.channel.send('Pong.');
            // await member.roles.add(Yard);
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
    if (reaction.message.partial) {
        try {
            let msg = await reaction.message.fetch()
            console.log(msg.id);
            if (msg.id === MessageNumber && reaction.emoji.name === '⚔️') {
                console.log('Cached - Applied');
                reaction.channel.send('Pong.');
                // applyRole();
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('Not a Partial');
        if (reaction.message.id === MessageNumber) {
            console.log('Not a Partial - applied')
            reaction.channel.send('Pong.');
            // applyRole();
        }
    }
});
```

Error:

```js
(node:11908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sorak\Desktop\dkp-bot\test.js:19:24)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageReactionAdd.handle (C:\Users\sorak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageReactionAdd.js:44:17)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD] (C:\Users\sorak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD.js:4:37)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\sorak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)     
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\sorak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\sorak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\sorak\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\sorak\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an 
async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11908) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm very new and would love some help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You already have variable with name `reaction`. Just **remove** the `let` from this line

`let reaction.channel.send = async () => {`

Comment: ```(node:15620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an 
async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)```

Comment: That something else now. Try wrapping the content of the function with `try` - `catch`.

Comment: awesome was able to log error, but jeez its huge and not sure what parts are helpful, as I've been coding for 3 days now. The error wont fit in one comment so I posted it here: https://hasteb.in/eyomisas.sql _also sorry for slow reply, was giving a presentation_

Answer (score 0):

There were a slew of errors I made in this code, for one I didn't do reaction.message.channel.send where I wanted the bot to send a message, I used emoji.id in place of reaction.emoji.name and other issues. (also didn't call back applyRole, which i later changed to sentMsg)

this is what finally was able to work for me:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE','REACTION']
});
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const MessageNumber = '710334220643336233'

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

bot.login(token);

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    console.log('Message Reaction Add Top');

    let sentMsg = async () => {
        try {
            let emojiName = reaction.emoji.name;
            let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find;
            let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id == user.id);
            if (reaction.emoji.name === '⚔️' && member) {
                console.log('React and Member Found');
                await reaction.message.channel.send('Pong.');
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
    if (reaction.message.partial) {
        try {
            let msg = await reaction.message.fetch()
            console.log(msg.id);
            if (msg.id === MessageNumber && reaction.emoji.name === '⚔️') {
                console.log('Cached - sent');
                sentMsg();
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('Not a Partial');
        if (reaction.message.id === MessageNumber) {
            console.log('Not a Partial - applied')
            // reaction.message.channel.send('piss smh');
            sentMsg();
        }
    }
});
```